# Images or JS not showing on Magento 2 installation

Tags: javascript, .htaccess, magento2

I've just installed Magento 2 onto my production server under a
 development. subdomain. The install appeared to have been successful
 but I've noticed there are no images or working javascript in both the
 frontend and the backend.

After inspecting the source code, I found that files being called in
 such as
`http://dev.website.com/pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/en_GB/css/print.css`
 don't actually exist. Any thoughts? I tried solutions on several
 stacks but haven't had any luck.

Answer (score 1):

> Try this Before that take **Backup**

Remove everything, except `.htaccess` file from `pub/static folder`

Open up `app/etc/di.xml` find the path `“Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Symlink”` and replace to `Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Copy`

Note: Remove entire files and folder under `pub/static` except `.htaccess` file.

For More info ref this http://www.dckap.com/blog/magento-2-admin-links-not-working-in-windows/

**Other Solution**

You can run below command from Magento root folder.

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

This will download the content perfectly in respective folders.